# R reference (documentation, specification)

Tags: r, multiplication

Is there a specification of R language that covers it?

For example I wanted to know what happens if you multiply a matrix and a vector (possibly transposed), the other way around. Using the standard `*` operator, not the `%*%` matrix multiplication. (Is it commutative?) I know I could find the specification of the behaviour for python or c++, but R?

One thing I found:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Operators

> [...] adding two vectors of the same length will create a vector containing the **element-wise** sums, implicitly looping over the vector index. This applies also to other operators like -, *****, and / as well as to **higher dimensional** structures. Notice in particular that multiplying two matrices does not produce the usual matrix product.

Then:

> [...] (matrix+matrix, dimensions must match. vector+matrix: first recycle, then check if dims fit, error if not)

I'm trying to decode what `first recycle, then check if dims fit` means.
Should the vector multiply rows of the matrix, or columns? Why should it check if some dims fit when it is recycled?

Like *first* check if #rows of the matrix is a multiple of the length of the vector? Or #rows times #cols is a multiple of length(vector)?

It does not seem as *the* specification though as it does not (?) answer such a basic question.

Comment: When you say *"Is there a specification of R language that covers it?"*, what does *"it"* refer to? Seems like maybe you mean standard multiplication with `*`? Or maybe matrix multiplication with `%*%`? Specifically for vectors, or matrices? Or maybe you're talking about recycling?

Comment: I meant that covers R language. The single specification in which I can look up a thing/situation concerning just the R language itself.

Comment: A matrix is just a vector with dims. In column-major order. Multiplying a vector by a matrix is the same as multiplying a vector by a vector and then trying to fit it into the `dim` of the original matrix --- it it doesn't fit it's an error.

Comment: Look up "recycling" separately. [here's "recycling rules](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Recycling-rules) in the doc you link. Here's [recyling](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) in an Intro to R. Recycling is always shorter object (smallest length) recylced to length or longer object, warning if not an even multiple. The `length` of a matrix is the number of elements. So if the matrix has more elements than the vector, the length of the matrix will be unchanged and the dims will fit.

Comment: Ok, so you (virtually) "stack" the columns of the matrix under each other so you have a vector and multiply it with the other vector which potentially gets recycles (actually the shorter one). So the rows*cols have to be a multiple of the vector length.

Comment: The rows*cols have to be a multiple of the vector length to avoid the warning about uneven recycling. `1:4 * matrix(11:16, nrow = 2)` does uneven recycling --- the 1 and 2 get recycled but the 3 and 4 don't. So you get a result with a warning about the uneven recycling.

Comment: See also [Arrays and Matrices in An Intro to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Arrays-and-matrices)

Comment: As far as an actual language definition, the best reference is probably the one cited in the `?matrix` help: Becker, R. A., Chambers, J. M. and Wilks, A. R. (1988) *The New S Language*. I believe there's a series of books.

Comment: Ok thanks, the intro looks more explanative even though one would think that the definition would be more precise.    If it were me I would formally define `contents` of an array as the vector of elements, column-major (somehow thay say so in the R definition). _And_ use it subsequently -> say that arithmetical operations on arrays (higher-dimensional structures) are performed on its `contents` with all the implications it has. Being the arithmetical operations on vectors that are already understandably defined.